# How to rearrange legend order in a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot with two legends, how can I rearrange the order of the legends of [this plot](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=NbKDhPQF&version=19), so that Sample Size appears below Party?

The docs show how to do this [for a qplo](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/guides.html)t, but I can't make the leap from that to the code I have.

Also didn't find [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_%28ggplot2%29/).

Comment: It is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143894/how-do-i-position-two-legends-independently-in-ggplot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `guides(size = guide_legend(order = 1))` to your plot. It works by specifying the position `size` should take.

Further information you will find when you read the documentation for `guides` and `guide_legend`.

Slightly adapted example from `?guide_legend`:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 1:20, y = 1:20, color = letters[1:5], size = LETTERS[1:2])
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = color, size = size))
p
```

[image]

```
p + guides(size = guide_legend(order = 1))
```

[image]