# Different legend position in the same plot ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to have different legend position in the same plot
Currently, I am using

```
theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

But I have two legends and would like to move one to the right and the other remain in the bottom.

```
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(grs, aes(x=grs$Pheno, y=grs$Type, weight=logp, colour=grs$Beta,size=logp))+
      geom_point(shape=15)+
geom_text(data=grs,size=4,color="black",mapping=aes(x=Pheno,y=Type,label=ifelse(logp>1.3,"x",'')))+
      scale_size_continuous(range=c(2,18),limits = c(0,25),breaks = c(1.3,seq(2,max(grs$logp),by = 2)))+
      scale_colour_gradientn(name="Beta",limits=c(-0.5, 0.5),colours = topo.colors(4))+
      scale_y_discrete("GRS")+
      theme(
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#696868", color = "orange", size = 2)
      )+
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "black",linetype = "dotted"))+
      theme(axis.text=bold.12.text)+
      theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank())+
      theme(axis.title.x=element_blank())+
      theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

Comment: You forgot to include the object `grs` to meet the reproducible example requirement

Comment: Some option here: [how-do-i-position-two-legends-independently-in-ggplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143894/how-do-i-position-two-legends-independently-in-ggplot/13327793#13327793)