# ggplot2 Creating a side and bottom legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to great a plot with one legend on the right side and one on the bottom. Both outside the map. I have tried a few suggestions but either both legends or neither legend moves.

```
library(ggthemes)
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(McMap)
County_Mayo_Map <- get_map("MAP", zoom=9)

p <- ggmap(County_Mayo_Map)
p <- p + geom_point(data=d, aes(lat, lon)) +
geom_point(stat = "identity") +
geom_point(data = d, aes(color = Name), size = 5) +
scale_shape_manual(values=df$x) +
geom_point(data = d, aes(shape = Town), size = 4) +
labs(caption = ("SPM 8-19-17")) +
labs(title = "Title", subtitle = "Subtitle") +
ylab("Latitude") +
xlab("Longitude") +
coord_fixed(ratio = 1/1) +
theme(legend.background = element_rect(
  fill ="lemonchiffon",
  colour = "black",
  size =1)) +
theme_solarized()
```

Comment: What is `McMap`? Have you forgotten to add something in the given code?

Comment: Maybe something from this can help: [how-do-i-position-two-legends-independently-in-ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143894/how-do-i-position-two-legends-independently-in-ggplot/13327793#13327793)

Comment: Thank you - I saw a line in the suggested code that might do the trick.