# Specifying different positions for multiple legends in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two legends, one from a `colour` argument, and one from a `fill` argument. By default, the two legends are placed on the right side of the plot. They can be moved together to the bottom of the plot with `legend.position()`, but I want to keep one legend on the right and move the other to the bottom. In the (trivial) reproducible example below, I would want the `var2` legend to stay on the right of the plot, and move only the `var1` legend to the bottom of the plot. Is it possible to do so?

```
d <- data.frame(var1 = sample(1:20, 20, replace = T),
                 var2 = runif(20),
                 x = rnorm(20),
                 y = rnorm(20))


ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_point(aes(colour = var1, size = var2))
```

**figure 1**

[image]

```
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_point(aes(colour = var1, size = var2)) + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.box = "vertical")
```

**figure 2**

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143894/how-do-i-position-two-legends-independently-in-ggplot)?

Comment: I had not, thanks! I must have not been using the right search terms :) Thanks for the edit with the figures too.

Comment: You are welcome. If you think the question solves your situation, you may want to remove your question. Otherwise, someone may mark it as  duplication.