# How to place legends at different sides of plot (bottom and right side) with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to get a plot with two legends, one at the bottom and the other at the right side of the plot.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(names = mtcars %>% 
  rownames(),
  mtcars)

#plot 1
p1 <- df %>% 
  filter(names == "Duster 360" | names == "Valiant") %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = mpg, color = names)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 20, linetype = "a")) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")

p1
```

[image]

Desired plot (legend should be outside of plot):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making use of `cowplot` you could do:

1. Extract the `color` guide from a plot without a `linetype` guide and `legend.position = "right"` using `cowplot::get_legend`
2. Making use of `cowplot::plot_grid` make a grid with two columns where the first column contains the plot without the `color` guide and the `linetype` guide placed at the bottom, while the `color` guide is put in the second column.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(names = mtcars %>% 
               rownames(),
             mtcars)

p1 <- df %>% 
  filter(names == "Duster 360" | names == "Valiant") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = mpg, color = names)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 20, linetype = "a"))

library(cowplot)

guide_color <- get_legend(p1 + guides(linetype = "none"))

plot_grid(p1 + 
            guides(color = "none") + 
            theme(legend.position = "bottom"), 
          guide_color, 
          ncol = 2, rel_widths = c(.85, .15))
```

[image]