# R show legend of data and trendline by group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot two groups by their data and trendline over time.  Ideally, I'd like the legend to show the groups as title with the rate and trendline below. Right now the legend is only showing for the group and not the trendline.  This is my dummy code:

```
week <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
hits <- c(262,698,239,195,122,160,746,283,557,239)
rate <- c(116, 134, 154, 185, 167, 216, 178, 242, 267, 234)
lower <- c(94, 111, 123, 145, 138, 196, 147, 204, 216, 176)
upper <- c(126, 167, 176, 225, 191, 245, 199, 287, 292, 267)
group <- c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B")
df <- data.frame(week = week, hits=hits, rate=rate, lower=lower, upper=upper,group=group)


ggplot(df, aes(x = week)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = rate, color = group)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, fill = group), 
              alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y = rate, color = group), method = 'lm',  
              size = 0.5, se = FALSE, linetype = "dashed",
              show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "black")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "black"))
```

[image]

**Edit**
So ideally the legend would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you say more what you mean by "groups as title with the rate and trendline below", maybe draw a picture?

Comment: Yes I've just added an edit to show the legend I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I only found a solution doing this manually using the library [`ggnewscale`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggnewscale/readme/README.html):

#### Manual approach

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = week)) + 
  geom_line(data = . %>% filter(group == 'A'), 
            aes(y = rate, color = 'Rate', linetype = 'Rate')) +
  geom_ribbon(data = . %>% filter(group == 'A'), 
              aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, fill = 'Rate'),
              alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_smooth(data = . %>% filter(group == 'A'), 
              aes(y = rate, color = 'Rate', linetype = 'Linear Trend'), method = 'lm',  
              size = 0.5, se = FALSE) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(Rate = 'solid', 'Linear Trend' = 'dashed'), name ='Group A', guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(Rate = 'red', 'Linear Trend' = 'red'), name = 'Group A', guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Rate = 'red', 'Linear Trend' = 'white'), name = 'Group A', guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  new_scale('linetype') +
  new_scale_color() +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_line(data = . %>% filter(group == 'B'), 
            aes(y = rate, color = 'Rate', linetype = 'Rate')) +
  geom_ribbon(data = . %>% filter(group == 'B'), 
              aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, fill = 'Rate'),
              alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_smooth(data = . %>% filter(group == 'B'), 
              aes(y = rate, color = 'Rate', linetype = 'Linear Trend'), method = 'lm',  
              size = 0.5, se = FALSE) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(Rate = 'solid', 'Linear Trend' = 'dashed'), name ='Group B') +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(Rate = 'black', 'Linear Trend' = 'black'), name = 'Group B') +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Rate = 'black', 'Linear Trend' = 'white'), name = 'Group B') +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(face="bold"))
```

First, this plots the data of group A and manually sets the legend entries. Then, new scales are created using `new_scale('linetype')`, `new_scale_color()` and `new_scale_fill()` from `ggnewscale`. After that, create the plots for group B and again, manually set the legend entries.

I assume there must be a better solution to this, in the meantime, I hope this helps you out!

#### Resulting plot

[image: resulting plot]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to have [multiple legends for the same aesthetic](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/11/multiple-legends-for-the-same-aesthetic-2/)

The instructions in the linked blog are somewhat dated (they refer to `show.guide` instead of `show.legend`), but following the idea there, you could do the following:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = week)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = rate, color = group), show.legend=TRUE) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, fill = group), 
              alpha = 0.2 ) + 
  geom_smooth(mapping=aes(y = rate, color = group), method = 'lm',  
              size = 0.5, se = FALSE, linetype = "dashed", show.legend=FALSE) +
 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "black"),  name='Group',
  guide=guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour=c("red", "black")))) +
 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "black"),  name='Trend',
  guide=guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour=c("red", "black"), linetype='dashed')))
```

The two final lines are key; basically you need to manually create the legends you want. Result:

[image]

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060601/ggplot-multiple-legends-arrangement) is also relevant.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer!  Ideally I'd like both, and for it to be divided by group and type of line, though I'm not sure if my data structure will allow this?