# In R, how to adjust multiple legend position separately in graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Here is one data.

```
Nitrogen= c(0, 50, 100, 0, 50, 100)
Season= c("2020yr", "2021yr", "2022yr", "2020yr", "2021yr", "2022yr")
Yield= c(20, 30, 55, 24, 29, 22)
df=data.frame(Nitrogen, Season, Yield)
```

and I grew a graph

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Nitrogen, y=Yield, fill=as.factor(Nitrogen), shape=Season)) + 
  geom_point(size=5) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(22, 22, 23), guide=guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour=1))) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkred", "darkblue", "darkgreen"), 
                    guide=guide_legend(override.aes= list(shape=21))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,120,40),limits=c(0,120)) +  
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,120,40),limits=c(0,120)) +  
  theme_classic(base_size=18, base_family="serif") +
  theme(legend.position=c(0.2,0.7),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.key=element_rect(color="white", fill="white"),
        legend.text=element_text(family="serif", face="plain",
                                 size=12, color="black"),
        legend.background= element_rect(fill="white"),
        axis.line = element_line(linewidth = 0.5, colour="black"))+
windows(width=5.5, height=5)
```

[image]

When I set up the legend position using `legend.position=c(0.2,0.7)` two legend is moving together.

I want to set up each legend position separately like below. Could you please let me know how to do that?

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: You can try adding `legend.box = "horizontal"` to your `theme`, this will give you two columns of legends separated by their mapped aesthetics (however, using `legend.position` will still move them together, I believe). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143894/how-do-i-position-two-legends-independently-in-ggplot might be relevant.

Comment: On a side note: since nitrogen content can be read from the x-axis, the colour coding is [redundant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chartjunk) and, worse, suggests an additional categorical variable where there is none. You might even do without the shapes and instead just label the years with `geom_text`.